# Jenkins OpenID Connect plugin - userInfoServerUrl

Tags: jenkins, openid-connect

Just got Jenkins configured with OpenID Connect but was wondering how it gets userInfoServerUrl. Is it retrieved from IdP metadata (/fss/.well-known/openid-configuration)?

If not, is there anyway to configure it?
The reason I am asking is that when I invoke the user info url manually, I do see token keys but Jenkins complains that the key is not supplied in the payload. The other issue is that it's not reading/populating mail and full name from the payload.

```
java.lang.Exception: no field 'uid' was suppied in the token payload to be used as the username
at org.kohsuke.stapler.HttpResponses.error(HttpResponses.java:83)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.oic.OicSecurityRealm$2.onSuccess(OicSecurityRealm.java:206)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.oic.OicSession.doFinishLogin(OicSession.java:98)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.oic.OicSecurityRealm.doFinishLogin(OicSecurityRealm.java:294)
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the option to set userInfoServerUrl will be available in the next release. See [github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/oic-auth-plugin/pull/1)